# Custom R package loads, shows help but does not provide functions

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

My custom package created with `devtools` installs, loads, displays help files for the functions, but does not provide the functions. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25287491/5967807) does not seem to be relevant, as my package is installed in `.libPaths()`.

```
# from the parent directory of the created package
install.packages("mypkg", repos = NULL, type = "source")
# ...
# * DONE (mypkg)
require(mypkg)
# Loading required package: mypkg
?my.fun        # displays the function help documentation correctly
my.fun()
```

> Error: could not find function "my.fun"

What causes this behaviour and how to fix it?

```
sessionInfo()
#R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
#Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
#Running under: OS X 10.13.1 (unknown)

#locale:
#[1] cs_CZ.UTF-8/cs_CZ.UTF-8/cs_CZ.UTF-8/C/cs_CZ.UTF-8/cs_CZ.UTF-8

#attached base packages:
#[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

#other attached packages:
#[1] mypkg_0.1    devtools_1.13.4

#loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#[1] tools_3.3.0   withr_2.1.0   memoise_1.0.0 git2r_0.19.0  digest_0.6.9
```

Comment: Did you export the function? To check if it's in the package run: `mypkg:::my.fun()`

Comment: @trosendal Thank you! Yes, that was it. Missed the `@export` tag in my function. If you change your comment to an answer, I'll provide credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you export the function? To check if it's in the package run:

```
mypkg:::my.fun()
```

Comment: I added `#' @export` to the function header and it worked. Thanks for noticing that.